# i keep getting an error that my list index is out of range

Tags: python, svm

im trying to get this SVM working, only i keep getting the error that my list index is out of range? can figure it out myself

```
[[self.ax.scatter(x[0],x[1],s=100) for x in data_dict[i]] for i in data_dict]
```

```
data_dict = {-1:np.array([[1,7],
                          [2,8],
                          [3.8],]),
             1:np.array([[5,1],
                         [6,1],
                         [7,3],])}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. Anyone should be able to copy the code and run it themselves to get the same error. Also, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 2):

I found your error.
Change this value from `[3.8],])`, to `[3,8],])`,

Notice the comma, instead of decimal point.